# How do you differentiate a Laplace transform?

Tags: laplace-transform, integral-transforms

Consider the Laplace transform of $\color{green}{t\cfrac{\mathrm{d^2}f}{\mathrm{d}t^2}}$:

$$\mathcal{L}\left[{t\cfrac{\mathrm{d^2}f}{\mathrm{d}t^2}}\right]=\int_{t=0}^{\infty}e^{-st}{t\cfrac{\mathrm{d^2}f}{\mathrm{d}t^2}}\mathrm{d}t=-\cfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}s}\int_{t=0}^{\infty}e^{-st}{\cfrac{\mathrm{d^2}f}{\mathrm{d}t^2}}\mathrm{d}t=\color{red}{-\cfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}s}\left[s^2\widetilde f(s)-sf(0)-f^{\prime}(0)\right]}=\color{blue}{-s^2\cfrac{\mathrm{d}\widetilde f}{\mathrm{d}s}-2s\widetilde f +f(0)}$$

Could someone please explain/show the steps that were taken to get from the $\color{red}{\mathrm{red}}$ expression to the $\color{blue}{\mathrm{blue}}$ expression?

Thanks.

Comment: This is not really about Laplace transforms.  Just think of $f(s)$ as any differentiable function, and the two expressions are equivalent: just use the product rule.

Comment: @Erick Your right, the Laplace transform is not the subject of this question but it is the context of this question. I still have no idea how to get from red expression to blue one. You said use the product rule, where is the product then? I'm afraid I need you to literally spell it out for me step by step in an answer then i'll accept it. And by the way, it must be something simple as what I have written here is actually from a textbook, so they just went straight from red to blue with no explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$s^2 \tilde{f}(s)$ is the *product* of the functions $s^2$ and $\tilde{f}(s)$.  By the product rule, the derivative of $s^2 \tilde{f}(s)$ with respect to $s$ is $$s^2 \frac{d\tilde{f}}{ds} + 2s \tilde{f}(s)$$.

$f(0)$ is constant (does not depend on $s$).  The derivative of $sf(0)$ is $f(0)$.  $f'(0)$ is also constant.  Its derivative is zero.

Comment: Thank you very much, exactly what I needed to see (+1)